# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ane'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, dictionary, keras

```
print(xtest.head())
print("predicted as",myModel.predict(xtest))
```

output:-

```
    age    bp    sg   al   su  rbc   pc  ...  rbcc  htn   dm  cad  appet   pe  ane
235  45.0  70.0  1.01  2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  ...   4.8  0.0  0.0  1.0    1.0  0.0  1.0

[1 rows x 24 columns]
predicted as  [[0.99633694]]
```

The xtest dataframe had a column named `ane` and the model is predicting well. But when I am giving the same input in form of dictionary as

```
di={'age': 59, 'bp': 70, 'sg': 1.01, 'al': 1.0, 'su': 3.0, 'rbc': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0, 'pcc': 0.0, 'ba': 0.0, 'bgr': 424.0, 'bu': 55.0, 'sc': 1.7, 'sod': 138.0, 'pot': 4.5, 'hemo': 12.0, 'pcv': 37.0, 'wbcc': 10200.0, 'rbcc': 4.1, 'htn': 1.0, 'dm': 1.0, 'cad': 1.0, 'appet': 1.0, 'pe': 0.0, 'ane': 1.0 }
b=pd.DataFrame(di.items())
b=b.T
x['ane'] = x['ane'].astype(float)
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(b, dtype=tf.float64)
print(myModel.predict((tensor)))
```

It's showing the following error:-

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ane'
```

In the training model, I did the same conversion and it worked well.

My colab notebook:-

```
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DomDo3adwRBQUFD0g8JVpF5jxC9HoegW
```

Comment: Please include the _compete_ error message and the definition of `x`.

Comment: I have uploaded the URL of whole source code in the colab notebook format.

Comment: Nope, that's not how it works on SO. Please ask a complete, reproducible, minimal question, will all the necessary code and complete error messages.

Comment: okay, I'll upload it from next time. Sorry for not obeying the policies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this code I replaced smae code in colab also.

```
import pandas as pd
di={'age': 59, 'bp': 70, 'sg': 1.01, 'al': 1.0, 'su': 3.0, 'rbc': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0, 'pcc': 0.0, 'ba': 0.0, 'bgr': 424.0, 'bu': 55.0, 'sc': 1.7, 'sod': 138.0, 'pot': 4.5, 'hemo': 12.0, 'pcv': 37.0, 'wbcc': 10200.0, 'rbcc': 4.1, 'htn': 1.0, 'dm': 1.0, 'cad': 1.0, 'appet': 1.0, 'pe': 0.0, 'ane': 1.0 }
b=pd.DataFrame(list(di.items()),index=di)
b= b.drop(columns=0)
b=b.T
b['ane'] = b['ane'].astype(float)
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(b, dtype=tf.float32)
print(myModel.predict((tensor)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! You did index=di but di is a list, so how the index was taken only as the keys?